# Date time format doesn't match when using strptime

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I have a string variable `start_d` that I need to convert to date and add 6 days to it. I've done:

```
end_d = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_d,'$d/%m/%Y')+datetime.timedelta(days=6)
```

But for some reason I get an error: `ValueError: time data '26/08/2019' does not match format '$d/%m/%Y'`

Not sure what I did wrong here.

Comment: You have `$d` instead of `%d`.

Comment: it has to be `%` instead of `$`